# Post to NewsFeed using SharePoint 2013 REST services from a workflow with POST method

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-designer, workflow, rest

In SharePoint 2013, workflows we can do a web service call. With this feature we can use SharePoint REST services within the workflow.

I want to post to the current users newsfeed from a workflow by using the SharePoint REST api for Social.
So I created a sharepoint 2013 site workflow in SPD. For the HTTP Web Service call I added dictionaries for request header and request content as below:

Request Header:

> Accept : application/json; odata=verbose
>
> Content-Type: application/json; odata=verbose

Request Content:

```
"restCreationData":
 {
  "__metadata":{
        "type":"SP.Social.SocialRestPostCreationData"
      },
  "ID":null,
  "creationData":{
        "__metadata":{
          "type":"SP.Social.SocialPostCreationData"
        },
        "ContentText":"This post was published using REST.", 
        "UpdateStatusText":false
  }
}
```

The workflow completes, but it did not post to the newsfeed.

Can anyone tell me what I have missed here?

Answer (score 1):

I have very similar problem and i use [fiddler for debugging](http://www.andrewconnell.com/blog/SP2013-Workflow-Advanced-Workflow-Debugging-with-Fiddler) and view web service request&response. 
I got follow stack trace:

```
   Microsoft.Office.Server.UserProfiles.UserProfileManager..ctor(UserProfileApplicationProxy userProfileApplicationProxy, Guid partitionID, Boolean IgnoreUserPrivacy, Boolean isWithinProfileSync, Boolean assumeProfileAdmin)
   at Microsoft.Office.Server.UserProfiles.UserProfileManager..ctor(UserProfileApplicationProxy userProfileApplicationProxy, Guid partitionID, Boolean IgnoreUserPrivacy, Boolean isWithinProfileSync)
   at Microsoft.Office.Server.UserProfiles.UserProfileManager..ctor(UserProfileApplicationProxy userProfileApplicationProxy, Guid partitionID, Boolean IgnoreUserPrivacy)
   at Microsoft.Office.Server.UserProfiles.ProfileLoader.get_UserProfileManager()
   at Microsoft.Office.Server.Microfeed.MBUtilities.GetUserProfile(String accountName, SPServiceContext context, MicrofeedLookupUserProfile lookupBy, Boolean& isFullProfile)
   at Microsoft.Office.Server.Social.SPSocialFeedManager.<.ctor>b__0()
   at Microsoft.Office.Server.Social.SPSocialUtil.InvokeWithExceptionTranslation(ISocialOperationManager target, String name, Action action)
   at Microsoft.Office.Server.Social.SPSocialRestFeedManager..ctor()
   at Microsoft.Office.Server.Social.SPSocialRestFeedManagerServerStub.InvokeConstructor(ClientValueCollection xmlargs, ProxyContext proxyContext)
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ServerStub.InvokeConstructorWithMonitoredScope(ClientValueCollection args, ProxyContext proxyContext)
```

I think `UserProfileManager` require `HttpContext.Current` but in workflow it doesn't exist because workflow running in other process in Workflow Manger.

You can try to experiment with [other api function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sharepoint/dn155789.aspx)